# Django adding multiple values to foreign key model

Tags: django

I have two models, one related to another by foreign key:

```
class Service(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class ServiceFile(models.Model):
    service_file = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    service = models.ForeignKey(Service)
```

Inside `views.py`, I want to grab `Service` contents along with its multiple `ServieFile` values (in order to pass it with context to template). How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

```
service = Service.objects.get(id=111) # service whose id is 111 for example
serv_files = ServiceFile.objects.filter(service=service)
```

Answer (score 2):

You only need to get `Service` in your context, it'll give you access to `ServiceFile` through a query that you can make directly in your template. For example, you context has `all_services` containing `Service.objects.all()`. Then, in your template:

```
// iterate over each service
{% for service in all_services %}
    // _set.all gets all ServiceFile objects that have a
    // specific service as foreign key.
    {% for servicefile in service.servicefile_set.all %}
       // You can access properties of each of these servicefiles.
       {{ servicefile.service_file }}
```